# Fragment get the wrong shared preference data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I'm storing an ArrayList and Int in Shared Preference, and in fragment i call storage.arraylist().get(storage.int()); to get the position in array but every activity get the right position except the fragment its get the wrong position

My goal is to make the fragment get the right position the int that is stored but he gets the backward of this int, if the int is 15 and the arraylist.size is 16 the fragment gets 14 but in any activity the get 15 position, i tried in fragment to just put in this int + 1 to get the right but the surprise he gets an error because the int it equal to the arraylist.size

Here Where i add an item to the arraylist

```
     storage.storeAudio(CardList.get(position));
            if(!app.ismServiceBound()) {
                fragment.setSlide_up();
            }
            app.PlayerBroadCast(1);
            fragment.Start();
```

The storeAudio Method

```
public void storeAudio(ModelCardView model) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (loadAudio() != null) {
        arrayList = loadAudio();
    }
    arrayList.add(model);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);
    editor.putString("audioArrayList", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

The execution of the BroadCast in the first code

```
        //Load data from SharedPreferences
        audioList = storage.loadAudio();
        audioIndex = audioList.size();
        audioIndex--;

        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            //index is in a valid range
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
            storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
```

In the end the fragment start to get the arraylist and the int to display some info

```
public void Start(){

    if(!app.ismServiceBound()) {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if (app.ismServiceBound() && storage.getState()) {
        start.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if(app.ismServiceBound() && !storage.getState()){
        start.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


        songName.setText(storage.loadAudio().get(storage.loadAudioIndex()).getId());
        bandName.setText(storage.loadAudio().get(storage.loadAudioIndex()).getSinger());

}
```

but its gets the wrong position i try to use the same code in activity and its work perfect without any problem but i don't know why in this fragment gets a wrong position, and Thanks for helping me.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to get the full context but what are you planning to do with `audioIndex--;`? I suspect it is that line there there is causing your index to be stored wrongly.

Comment: if its stored wrongly won't the rest of the activity gets the right positions

Comment: Sorry! I'm afraid there isn't enough code to make a conclusion on where the issue might be.